# Problem with a spice model in Proteus

Tags: spice, proteus, model

Hil all, how are you?. I'm trying to simulate the IR2110 in proteus ISIS (is not modelled nativelly), then I've downloaded the model from infineon and followed the tutorial from labcenter to make de device, after make the device then I tried to simulate the new device but I'm having an error in PROSPICE which says "Too few parameters for subcircuit type "IR2110" (instance: xU2)" where the code of the model is the following:

```
**********************************************************************
```

*
*  Copyright (c) International Rectifier
*
*  IR2110: High and Low Side Driver
*
*  Ports 
*    VDD: Logic Supply
*    HIN: Logic Input for High Side Gate Driver Output (HO), in phase
*    SD:  Logic Input for Shutdown
*    LIN: Logic Input for Low Side Gate Driver Output (LO), in phase
*    VSS: Logic Ground
*    VB:  High Side Floating Supply 
*    HO:  High Side Gate Diver Output
*    VS:  High Side Floating Supply Return
*    VC: Low Side Supply
*    LO:  Low Side Gate Driver Output
*    COM: Low Side Return
*
*  Created by Pspice Version 8 
*
*  Date Created: 03/25/2003
*

---

*
*  This behavioral model was developed in compliance with Data Sheet 
*  No. PD60147-R except noted below: 
*  (1) There is no frequency effect on temperature.
*  (2) The power dissipation is different. 
*  (3) The values of output high/low short circuit current are adjusted 
*      for the proper modeling of turn-on rise/turn-off fall time.
*  (4) The "Low side return (COM)" pin must be grounded.

---

.SUBCKT IR2110 VDD HIN SD LIN VSS HO VB VS VC COM LO 
+PARAMS:
+         T1=-40 T2=25 T3=125
+         V1=10 V2=15 V3=20
+         tonT1=90n tonT2=120n tonT3=170n
+         tonV1=140n tonV2=120n tonV3=100n
+         toffT1=77n toffT2=94n toffT3=130n
+         toffV1=115n toffV2=94n toffV3=75n
+         tonVdd1=125n tonVdd2=120n tonVdd3=115n
+         toffVdd1=113n toffVdd2=94n toffVdd3=72n

.MODEL diode25 d
+IS=1.0e-14 RS=0.01 N=1 EG=1.11
+XTI=3 BV=25 IBV=0.0001 CJO=0
+VJ=0.75 M=0.333 FC=0.5 TT=0
+KF=0 AF=1

.MODEL diode525 d
+IS=1.0e-14 RS=0.01 N=1 EG=1.11
+XTI=3 BV=525 IBV=0.0001 CJO=0
+VJ=0.75 M=0.333 FC=0.5 TT=0
+KF=0 AF=1

C_MD1_C2         VSS MD2_Nor3b_2  10p
C_MD1_C3         VSS MD2_Inv2_1  10p
C_MD1_C1         VSS MD2_Inv1_1  1n
D_MD1_D2         VSS HIN diode25 
D_MD1_D3         SD VDD diode25 
D_MD1_D4         VSS SD diode25 
D_MD1_D5         LIN VDD diode25 
D_MD1_D6         VSS LIN diode25 
D_MD1_D7         VSS VDD diode25 
D_MD1_D1         HIN VDD diode25 
C_MD1_Trig3_CTrig         VSS MD2_Inv2_1  10p
R_MD1_Trig3_R1Trig         MD1_Trig3_3 VDD  100Meg
R_MD1_Trig3_R2Trig         MD1_Trig3_4 MD1_Trig3_3  66.7Meg
R_MD1_Trig3_R3Trig         VSS MD1_Trig3_4  106.1Meg
X_MD1_Trig3_Comp         LIN MD1_Trig3_3 MD2_Inv2_1 com COMP
S_MD1_Trig3_PTrig         MD1_Trig3_4 VSS MD2_Inv2_1 VSS _MD1_Trig3_PTrig
RS_MD1_Trig3_PTrig        MD2_Inv2_1 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD1_Trig3_PTrig VSWITCH Roff=1e9 Ron=1 Voff=0.01 Von=4.99
R_MD1_R1         VSS HIN 750k TC=-0.00783811, 0.0000372046
R_MD1_R2         VSS SD 750k TC=-0.00783811, 0.0000372046
C_MD1_Trig1_CTrig         VSS MD2_Inv1_1  10p
R_MD1_Trig1_R1Trig         MD1_Trig1_3 VDD  100Meg
R_MD1_Trig1_R2Trig         MD1_Trig1_4 MD1_Trig1_3  66.7Meg
R_MD1_Trig1_R3Trig         VSS MD1_Trig1_4  106.1Meg
X_MD1_Trig1_Comp         HIN MD1_Trig1_3 MD2_Inv1_1 com COMP
S_MD1_Trig1_PTrig         MD1_Trig1_4 VSS MD2_Inv1_1 VSS _MD1_Trig1_PTrig
RS_MD1_Trig1_PTrig        MD2_Inv1_1 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD1_Trig1_PTrig VSWITCH Roff=1e9 Ron=1 Voff=0.01 Von=4.99
C_MD1_Trig2_CTrig         VSS MD2_Nor3b_2  10p
R_MD1_Trig2_R1Trig         MD1_Trig2_3 VDD  100Meg
R_MD1_Trig2_R2Trig         MD1_Trig2_4 MD1_Trig2_3  66.7Meg
R_MD1_Trig2_R3Trig         VSS MD1_Trig2_4  106.1Meg
X_MD1_Trig2_Comp         SD MD1_Trig2_3 MD2_Nor3b_2 com COMP
S_MD1_Trig2_PTrig         MD1_Trig2_4 VSS MD2_Nor3b_2 VSS _MD1_Trig2_PTrig
RS_MD1_Trig2_PTrig        MD2_Nor3b_2 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD1_Trig2_PTrig VSWITCH Roff=1e9 Ron=1 Voff=0.01 Von=4.99
R_MD1_R3         VSS LIN 750k TC=-0.00783811, 0.0000372046
R_MD1_R4         VSS VDD 7.5Meg TC=-0.00505291, 0.0000236999
C_MD2_C1         VSS MD3_DlyHS_2  10p IC=0 
C_MD2_C2         VSS MD3_DlyLS_2  10p IC=0 
V_MD2_Inv1_V         MD2_Inv1_2 VSS 5V
C_MD2_Inv1_C         VSS MD2_Nor3a_3  1p
S_MD2_Inv1_P         MD2_Inv1_2 MD2_Nor3a_3 MD2_Inv1_1 VSS _MD2_Inv1_P
RS_MD2_Inv1_P        MD2_Inv1_1 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD2_Inv1_P VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=4.9V Von=0.1V
S_MD2_Inv1_N         MD2_Nor3a_3 VSS MD2_Inv1_1 VSS _MD2_Inv1_N
RS_MD2_Inv1_N        MD2_Inv1_1 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD2_Inv1_N VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=0.1V Von=4.9V
V_MD2_Inv2_V         MD2_Inv2_2 VSS 5V
C_MD2_Inv2_C         VSS MD2_Nor3b_1  1p
S_MD2_Inv2_P         MD2_Inv2_2 MD2_Nor3b_1 MD2_Inv2_1 VSS _MD2_Inv2_P
RS_MD2_Inv2_P        MD2_Inv2_1 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD2_Inv2_P VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=4.9V Von=0.1V
S_MD2_Inv2_N         MD2_Nor3b_1 VSS MD2_Inv2_1 VSS _MD2_Inv2_N
RS_MD2_Inv2_N        MD2_Inv2_1 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD2_Inv2_N VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=0.1V Von=4.9V
C_MD2_RS1_C7         MD2_RS1_6 MD2_RS1_5  10p
C_MD2_RS1_C2         VSS MD2_Nor3a_3  10p IC=0 
C_MD2_RS1_C3         VSS MD2_Nor3b_2  10p IC=0 
C_MD2_RS1_C10         MD2_RS1_7 MD2_RS1_5  10p
C_MD2_RS1_C11         MD2_RS1_3 MD2_RS1_7  10p
C_MD2_RS1_C12         VSS MD2_RS1_3  10p
C_MD2_RS1_C9         VSS MD2_Nor3a_1  10p
C_MD2_RS1_C8         MD2_Nor3a_1 MD2_RS1_6  10p
C_MD2_RS1_C1         VSS MD2_Nor3a_1  10p IC=0 
S_MD2_RS1_P1         MD2_RS1_5 MD2_RS1_6 MD2_Nor3a_3 VSS _MD2_RS1_P1
RS_MD2_RS1_P1        MD2_Nor3a_3 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD2_RS1_P1 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1m Voff=4.9V Von=0.1V
S_MD2_RS1_P2         MD2_RS1_6 MD2_Nor3a_1 MD2_RS1_3 VSS _MD2_RS1_P2
RS_MD2_RS1_P2        MD2_RS1_3 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD2_RS1_P2 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1m Voff=4.9V Von=0.1V
S_MD2_RS1_N1         MD2_Nor3a_1 VSS MD2_RS1_3 VSS _MD2_RS1_N1
RS_MD2_RS1_N1        MD2_RS1_3 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD2_RS1_N1 VSWITCH Roff=1e8 Ron=1m Voff=0.1V Von=4.9V
S_MD2_RS1_P3         MD2_RS1_5 MD2_RS1_7 MD2_Nor3b_2 VSS _MD2_RS1_P3
RS_MD2_RS1_P3        MD2_Nor3b_2 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD2_RS1_P3 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1m Voff=4.9V Von=0.1V
S_MD2_RS1_P4         MD2_RS1_7 MD2_RS1_3 MD2_Nor3a_1 VSS _MD2_RS1_P4
RS_MD2_RS1_P4        MD2_Nor3a_1 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD2_RS1_P4 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1m Voff=4.9V Von=0.1V
S_MD2_RS1_N3         MD2_RS1_3 VSS MD2_Nor3b_2 VSS _MD2_RS1_N3
RS_MD2_RS1_N3        MD2_Nor3b_2 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD2_RS1_N3 VSWITCH Roff=1e8 Ron=1m Voff=0.1V Von=4.9V
V_MD2_RS1_V1         MD2_RS1_5 VSS 5V
S_MD2_RS1_N4         MD2_RS1_3 VSS MD2_Nor3a_1 VSS _MD2_RS1_N4
RS_MD2_RS1_N4        MD2_Nor3a_1 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD2_RS1_N4 VSWITCH Roff=1e8 Ron=1m Voff=0.1V Von=4.9V
S_MD2_RS1_N2         MD2_Nor3a_1 VSS MD2_Nor3a_3 VSS _MD2_RS1_N2
RS_MD2_RS1_N2        MD2_Nor3a_3 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD2_RS1_N2 VSWITCH Roff=1e8 Ron=1m Voff=0.1V Von=4.9V
C_MD2_RS2_C7         MD2_RS2_6 MD2_RS2_5  10p
C_MD2_RS2_C2         VSS MD2_Nor3b_1  10p IC=0 
C_MD2_RS2_C3         VSS MD2_Nor3b_2  10p IC=0 
C_MD2_RS2_C10         MD2_RS2_7 MD2_RS2_5  10p
C_MD2_RS2_C11         MD2_RS2_3 MD2_RS2_7  10p
C_MD2_RS2_C12         VSS MD2_RS2_3  10p
C_MD2_RS2_C9         VSS MD2_Nor3b_3  10p
C_MD2_RS2_C8         MD2_Nor3b_3 MD2_RS2_6  10p
C_MD2_RS2_C1         VSS MD2_Nor3b_3  10p IC=0 
S_MD2_RS2_P1         MD2_RS2_5 MD2_RS2_6 MD2_Nor3b_1 VSS _MD2_RS2_P1
RS_MD2_RS2_P1        MD2_Nor3b_1 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD2_RS2_P1 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1m Voff=4.9V Von=0.1V
S_MD2_RS2_P2         MD2_RS2_6 MD2_Nor3b_3 MD2_RS2_3 VSS _MD2_RS2_P2
RS_MD2_RS2_P2        MD2_RS2_3 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD2_RS2_P2 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1m Voff=4.9V Von=0.1V
S_MD2_RS2_N1         MD2_Nor3b_3 VSS MD2_RS2_3 VSS _MD2_RS2_N1
RS_MD2_RS2_N1        MD2_RS2_3 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD2_RS2_N1 VSWITCH Roff=1e8 Ron=1m Voff=0.1V Von=4.9V
S_MD2_RS2_P3         MD2_RS2_5 MD2_RS2_7 MD2_Nor3b_2 VSS _MD2_RS2_P3
RS_MD2_RS2_P3        MD2_Nor3b_2 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD2_RS2_P3 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1m Voff=4.9V Von=0.1V
S_MD2_RS2_P4         MD2_RS2_7 MD2_RS2_3 MD2_Nor3b_3 VSS _MD2_RS2_P4
RS_MD2_RS2_P4        MD2_Nor3b_3 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD2_RS2_P4 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1m Voff=4.9V Von=0.1V
S_MD2_RS2_N3         MD2_RS2_3 VSS MD2_Nor3b_2 VSS _MD2_RS2_N3
RS_MD2_RS2_N3        MD2_Nor3b_2 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD2_RS2_N3 VSWITCH Roff=1e8 Ron=1m Voff=0.1V Von=4.9V
V_MD2_RS2_V1         MD2_RS2_5 VSS 5V
S_MD2_RS2_N4         MD2_RS2_3 VSS MD2_Nor3b_3 VSS _MD2_RS2_N4
RS_MD2_RS2_N4        MD2_Nor3b_3 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD2_RS2_N4 VSWITCH Roff=1e8 Ron=1m Voff=0.1V Von=4.9V
S_MD2_RS2_N2         MD2_Nor3b_3 VSS MD2_Nor3b_1 VSS _MD2_RS2_N2
RS_MD2_RS2_N2        MD2_Nor3b_1 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD2_RS2_N2 VSWITCH Roff=1e8 Ron=1m Voff=0.1V Von=4.9V
S_MD2_Nor3a_P1         MD2_Nor3a_4 MD2_Nor3a_5 MD2_Nor3a_1 VSS _MD2_Nor3a_P1
RS_MD2_Nor3a_P1        MD2_Nor3a_1 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD2_Nor3a_P1 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=4.9V Von=0.1V
S_MD2_Nor3a_P2         MD2_Nor3a_5 MD2_Nor3a_6 MD2_Nor3b_2 VSS _MD2_Nor3a_P2
RS_MD2_Nor3a_P2        MD2_Nor3b_2 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD2_Nor3a_P2 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=4.9V Von=0.1V
S_MD2_Nor3a_P3         MD2_Nor3a_6 MD3_DlyHS_2 MD2_Nor3a_3 VSS _MD2_Nor3a_P3
RS_MD2_Nor3a_P3        MD2_Nor3a_3 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD2_Nor3a_P3 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=4.9V Von=0.1V
S_MD2_Nor3a_N1         MD3_DlyHS_2 VSS MD2_Nor3b_2 VSS _MD2_Nor3a_N1
RS_MD2_Nor3a_N1        MD2_Nor3b_2 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD2_Nor3a_N1 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=0.1V Von=4.9V
V_MD2_Nor3a_V         MD2_Nor3a_4 VSS 5V
S_MD2_Nor3a_N2         MD3_DlyHS_2 VSS MD2_Nor3a_1 VSS _MD2_Nor3a_N2
RS_MD2_Nor3a_N2        MD2_Nor3a_1 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD2_Nor3a_N2 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=0.1V Von=4.9V
S_MD2_Nor3a_N3         MD3_DlyHS_2 VSS MD2_Nor3a_3 VSS _MD2_Nor3a_N3
RS_MD2_Nor3a_N3        MD2_Nor3a_3 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD2_Nor3a_N3 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=0.1V Von=4.9V
S_MD2_Nor3b_P1         MD2_Nor3b_4 MD2_Nor3b_5 MD2_Nor3b_1 VSS _MD2_Nor3b_P1
RS_MD2_Nor3b_P1        MD2_Nor3b_1 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD2_Nor3b_P1 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=4.9V Von=0.1V
S_MD2_Nor3b_P2         MD2_Nor3b_5 MD2_Nor3b_6 MD2_Nor3b_2 VSS _MD2_Nor3b_P2
RS_MD2_Nor3b_P2        MD2_Nor3b_2 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD2_Nor3b_P2 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=4.9V Von=0.1V
S_MD2_Nor3b_P3         MD2_Nor3b_6 MD3_DlyLS_2 MD2_Nor3b_3 VSS _MD2_Nor3b_P3
RS_MD2_Nor3b_P3        MD2_Nor3b_3 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD2_Nor3b_P3 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=4.9V Von=0.1V
S_MD2_Nor3b_N1         MD3_DlyLS_2 VSS MD2_Nor3b_2 VSS _MD2_Nor3b_N1
RS_MD2_Nor3b_N1        MD2_Nor3b_2 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD2_Nor3b_N1 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=0.1V Von=4.9V
V_MD2_Nor3b_V         MD2_Nor3b_4 VSS 5V
S_MD2_Nor3b_N2         MD3_DlyLS_2 VSS MD2_Nor3b_1 VSS _MD2_Nor3b_N2
RS_MD2_Nor3b_N2        MD2_Nor3b_1 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD2_Nor3b_N2 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=0.1V Von=4.9V
S_MD2_Nor3b_N3         MD3_DlyLS_2 VSS MD2_Nor3b_3 VSS _MD2_Nor3b_N3
RS_MD2_Nor3b_N3        MD2_Nor3b_3 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD2_Nor3b_N3 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=0.1V Von=4.9V
D_MD5_D2         com LO diode25 
D_MD5_D1         LO VC diode25 
C_MD5_C         com LO  10p
C_MD5_UVC_c1         MD5_UVC_2 MD5_UVC_3  10n
C_MD5_UVC_c2         MD5_UVC_4 MD5_UVC_2  10n
C_MD5_UVC_c3         com MD4_Inv5_1  10p
E_MD5_UVC_ABM2         MD5_UVC_3 com   VALUE { 8.3+(8.8-8.3)/(125+40)*(TEMP+40)

+   }
E_MD5_UVC_ABM3         MD5_UVC_4 com   VALUE { 8.0+(8.5-8.0)/(125+40)*(TEMP+40)
+   }
X_MD5_UVC_Comp         VC MD5_UVC_2 MD4_Inv5_1 com COMP
S_MD5_UVC_P         MD5_UVC_3 MD5_UVC_2 MD4_Inv5_1 com _MD5_UVC_P
RS_MD5_UVC_P        MD4_Inv5_1 com 1G
.MODEL        _MD5_UVC_P VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=4.99 Von=0.01
S_MD5_UVC_N         MD5_UVC_2 MD5_UVC_4 MD4_Inv5_1 com _MD5_UVC_N
RS_MD5_UVC_N        MD4_Inv5_1 com 1G
.MODEL        _MD5_UVC_N VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=0.01 Von=4.99
S_MD5_Nand_P1         MD5_Nand_5 MD5_OLS_1 MD4_Inv5_1 VSS _MD5_Nand_P1
RS_MD5_Nand_P1        MD4_Inv5_1 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD5_Nand_P1 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=4.9 Von=0.1
S_MD5_Nand_N1         MD5_OLS_1 MD5_Nand_4 MD3_DlyLS_8 VSS _MD5_Nand_N1
RS_MD5_Nand_N1        MD3_DlyLS_8 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD5_Nand_N1 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=0.1 Von=4.9
S_MD5_Nand_P2         MD5_Nand_5 MD5_OLS_1 MD3_DlyLS_8 VSS _MD5_Nand_P2
RS_MD5_Nand_P2        MD3_DlyLS_8 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD5_Nand_P2 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=4.9 Von=0.1
V_MD5_Nand_V         MD5_Nand_5 VSS 5V
S_MD5_Nand_N2         MD5_Nand_4 VSS MD4_Inv5_1 VSS _MD5_Nand_N2
RS_MD5_Nand_N2        MD4_Inv5_1 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD5_Nand_N2 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=0.1 Von=4.9
S_MD5_OLS_P         VC MD5_OLS_2 MD5_OLS_1 com _MD5_OLS_P
RS_MD5_OLS_P        MD5_OLS_1 com 1G
.MODEL        _MD5_OLS_P VSWITCH Roff=1e9 Ron=1m Voff=4.9 Von=0.1
S_MD5_OLS_N         MD5_OLS_3 com MD5_OLS_1 com _MD5_OLS_N
RS_MD5_OLS_N        MD5_OLS_1 com 1G
.MODEL        _MD5_OLS_N VSWITCH Roff=1e9 Ron=1m Voff=0.1 Von=4.9
R_MD5_OLS_R6         LO MD5_OLS_2 11.4 TC=0.00190676, 9.3240e-07
R_MD5_OLS_R7         MD5_OLS_3 LO 7.76 TC=0.00241396, 2.331e-06
R_MD5_R         com VC 83.3k TC=-0.00358599, 0.0000124556
D_MD5_D3         com VC diode25 
D_MD4_D2         HO VB diode25 
D_MD4_D1         VS VB diode25 
D_MD4_D4         com VB diode525 
D_MD4_D5         com VS diode525 
D_MD4_D3         VS HO diode25 
C_MD4_C3         VS HO  10p IC=0 
C_MD4_Uvbs_c1         MD4_Uvbs_2 MD4_Uvbs_4  10n
C_MD4_Uvbs_c2         MD4_Uvbs_5 MD4_Uvbs_2  10n
C_MD4_Uvbs_c3         com MD4_Inv4_1  10p
E_MD4_Uvbs_ABM18         MD4_Uvbs_4 com   VALUE {
+  V(VS)+8.4+(8.9-8.4)/(125+40)*(TEMP+40)     }
E_MD4_Uvbs_ABM19         MD4_Uvbs_5 com   VALUE {
+  V(VS)+8.0+(8.45-8.0)/(125+40)*(TEMP+40)    }
X_MD4_Uvbs_Comp         VB MD4_Uvbs_2 MD4_Inv4_1 com COMP
S_MD4_Uvbs_P         MD4_Uvbs_4 MD4_Uvbs_2 MD4_Inv4_1 com _MD4_Uvbs_P
RS_MD4_Uvbs_P        MD4_Inv4_1 com 1G
.MODEL        _MD4_Uvbs_P VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=4.99 Von=0.01
S_MD4_Uvbs_N         MD4_Uvbs_2 MD4_Uvbs_5 MD4_Inv4_1 com _MD4_Uvbs_N
RS_MD4_Uvbs_N        MD4_Inv4_1 com 1G
.MODEL        _MD4_Uvbs_N VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=0.01 Von=4.99
V_MD4_Inv3_V         MD4_Inv3_2 VSS 5V
C_MD4_Inv3_C         VSS MD4_OHS_1  1p
S_MD4_Inv3_P         MD4_Inv3_2 MD4_OHS_1 MD4_RS_4 VSS _MD4_Inv3_P
RS_MD4_Inv3_P        MD4_RS_4 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD4_Inv3_P VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=4.9V Von=0.1V
S_MD4_Inv3_N         MD4_OHS_1 VSS MD4_RS_4 VSS _MD4_Inv3_N
RS_MD4_Inv3_N        MD4_RS_4 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD4_Inv3_N VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=0.1V Von=4.9V
C_MD4_RS_C7         MD4_RS_6 MD4_RS_5  10p
C_MD4_RS_C2         VSS MD4_Inv2_3  10p IC=0 
C_MD4_RS_C3         VSS MD3_DlyHS_8  10p IC=0 
C_MD4_RS_C10         MD4_RS_7 MD4_RS_5  10p
C_MD4_RS_C11         MD4_RS_3 MD4_RS_7  10p
C_MD4_RS_C12         VSS MD4_RS_3  10p
C_MD4_RS_C9         VSS MD4_RS_4  10p
C_MD4_RS_C8         MD4_RS_4 MD4_RS_6  10p
C_MD4_RS_C1         VSS MD4_RS_4  10p IC=0 
S_MD4_RS_P1         MD4_RS_5 MD4_RS_6 MD4_Inv2_3 VSS _MD4_RS_P1
RS_MD4_RS_P1        MD4_Inv2_3 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD4_RS_P1 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1m Voff=4.9V Von=0.1V
S_MD4_RS_P2         MD4_RS_6 MD4_RS_4 MD4_RS_3 VSS _MD4_RS_P2
RS_MD4_RS_P2        MD4_RS_3 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD4_RS_P2 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1m Voff=4.9V Von=0.1V
S_MD4_RS_N1         MD4_RS_4 VSS MD4_RS_3 VSS _MD4_RS_N1
RS_MD4_RS_N1        MD4_RS_3 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD4_RS_N1 VSWITCH Roff=1e8 Ron=1m Voff=0.1V Von=4.9V
S_MD4_RS_P3         MD4_RS_5 MD4_RS_7 MD3_DlyHS_8 VSS _MD4_RS_P3
RS_MD4_RS_P3        MD3_DlyHS_8 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD4_RS_P3 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1m Voff=4.9V Von=0.1V
S_MD4_RS_P4         MD4_RS_7 MD4_RS_3 MD4_RS_4 VSS _MD4_RS_P4
RS_MD4_RS_P4        MD4_RS_4 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD4_RS_P4 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1m Voff=4.9V Von=0.1V
S_MD4_RS_N3         MD4_RS_3 VSS MD3_DlyHS_8 VSS _MD4_RS_N3
RS_MD4_RS_N3        MD3_DlyHS_8 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD4_RS_N3 VSWITCH Roff=1e8 Ron=1m Voff=0.1V Von=4.9V
V_MD4_RS_V1         MD4_RS_5 VSS 5V
S_MD4_RS_N4         MD4_RS_3 VSS MD4_RS_4 VSS _MD4_RS_N4
RS_MD4_RS_N4        MD4_RS_4 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD4_RS_N4 VSWITCH Roff=1e8 Ron=1m Voff=0.1V Von=4.9V
S_MD4_RS_N2         MD4_RS_4 VSS MD4_Inv2_3 VSS _MD4_RS_N2
RS_MD4_RS_N2        MD4_Inv2_3 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD4_RS_N2 VSWITCH Roff=1e8 Ron=1m Voff=0.1V Von=4.9V
V_MD4_Inv2_V         MD4_Inv2_2 VSS 5V
C_MD4_Inv2_C         VSS MD4_Inv2_3  1p
S_MD4_Inv2_P         MD4_Inv2_2 MD4_Inv2_3 MD4_Nor1_5 VSS _MD4_Inv2_P
RS_MD4_Inv2_P        MD4_Nor1_5 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD4_Inv2_P VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=4.9V Von=0.1V
S_MD4_Inv2_N         MD4_Inv2_3 VSS MD4_Nor1_5 VSS _MD4_Inv2_N
RS_MD4_Inv2_N        MD4_Nor1_5 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD4_Inv2_N VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=0.1V Von=4.9V
V_MD4_Inv1_V         MD4_Inv1_2 VSS 5V
C_MD4_Inv1_C         VSS MD4_Nor1_1  1p
S_MD4_Inv1_P         MD4_Inv1_2 MD4_Nor1_1 MD3_DlyHS_8 VSS _MD4_Inv1_P
RS_MD4_Inv1_P        MD3_DlyHS_8 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD4_Inv1_P VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=4.9V Von=0.1V
S_MD4_Inv1_N         MD4_Nor1_1 VSS MD3_DlyHS_8 VSS _MD4_Inv1_N
RS_MD4_Inv1_N        MD3_DlyHS_8 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD4_Inv1_N VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=0.1V Von=4.9V
V_MD4_Inv4_V         MD4_Inv4_2 VSS 5V
C_MD4_Inv4_C         VSS MD4_Nor2_2  1p
S_MD4_Inv4_P         MD4_Inv4_2 MD4_Nor2_2 MD4_Inv4_1 VSS _MD4_Inv4_P
RS_MD4_Inv4_P        MD4_Inv4_1 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD4_Inv4_P VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=4.9V Von=0.1V
S_MD4_Inv4_N         MD4_Nor2_2 VSS MD4_Inv4_1 VSS _MD4_Inv4_N
RS_MD4_Inv4_N        MD4_Inv4_1 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD4_Inv4_N VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=0.1V Von=4.9V
V_MD4_Nor1_V         MD4_Nor1_3 VSS 5V
S_MD4_Nor1_P1         MD4_Nor1_3 MD4_Nor1_4 MD4_Nor1_1 VSS _MD4_Nor1_P1
RS_MD4_Nor1_P1        MD4_Nor1_1 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD4_Nor1_P1 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=4.9 Von=0.1
S_MD4_Nor1_P2         MD4_Nor1_4 MD4_Nor1_5 MD4_Inv6_3 VSS _MD4_Nor1_P2
RS_MD4_Nor1_P2        MD4_Inv6_3 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD4_Nor1_P2 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=4.9 Von=0.1
S_MD4_Nor1_N1         MD4_Nor1_5 VSS MD4_Inv6_3 VSS _MD4_Nor1_N1
RS_MD4_Nor1_N1        MD4_Inv6_3 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD4_Nor1_N1 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=0.1 Von=4.9
S_MD4_Nor1_N2         MD4_Nor1_5 VSS MD4_Nor1_1 VSS _MD4_Nor1_N2
RS_MD4_Nor1_N2        MD4_Nor1_1 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD4_Nor1_N2 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=0.1 Von=4.9
V_MD4_Inv5_V         MD4_Inv5_2 VSS 5V
C_MD4_Inv5_C         VSS MD4_Nor2_1  1p
S_MD4_Inv5_P         MD4_Inv5_2 MD4_Nor2_1 MD4_Inv5_1 VSS _MD4_Inv5_P
RS_MD4_Inv5_P        MD4_Inv5_1 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD4_Inv5_P VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=4.9V Von=0.1V
S_MD4_Inv5_N         MD4_Nor2_1 VSS MD4_Inv5_1 VSS _MD4_Inv5_N
RS_MD4_Inv5_N        MD4_Inv5_1 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD4_Inv5_N VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=0.1V Von=4.9V
V_MD4_Nor2_V         MD4_Nor2_3 VSS 5V
S_MD4_Nor2_P1         MD4_Nor2_3 MD4_Nor2_4 MD4_Nor2_1 VSS _MD4_Nor2_P1
RS_MD4_Nor2_P1        MD4_Nor2_1 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD4_Nor2_P1 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=4.9 Von=0.1
S_MD4_Nor2_P2         MD4_Nor2_4 MD4_Inv6_1 MD4_Nor2_2 VSS _MD4_Nor2_P2
RS_MD4_Nor2_P2        MD4_Nor2_2 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD4_Nor2_P2 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=4.9 Von=0.1
S_MD4_Nor2_N1         MD4_Inv6_1 VSS MD4_Nor2_2 VSS _MD4_Nor2_N1
RS_MD4_Nor2_N1        MD4_Nor2_2 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD4_Nor2_N1 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=0.1 Von=4.9
S_MD4_Nor2_N2         MD4_Inv6_1 VSS MD4_Nor2_1 VSS _MD4_Nor2_N2
RS_MD4_Nor2_N2        MD4_Nor2_1 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD4_Nor2_N2 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=0.1 Von=4.9
V_MD4_Inv6_V         MD4_Inv6_2 VSS 5V
C_MD4_Inv6_C         VSS MD4_Inv6_3  1p
S_MD4_Inv6_P         MD4_Inv6_2 MD4_Inv6_3 MD4_Inv6_1 VSS _MD4_Inv6_P
RS_MD4_Inv6_P        MD4_Inv6_1 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD4_Inv6_P VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=4.9V Von=0.1V
S_MD4_Inv6_N         MD4_Inv6_3 VSS MD4_Inv6_1 VSS _MD4_Inv6_N
RS_MD4_Inv6_N        MD4_Inv6_1 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD4_Inv6_N VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=0.1V Von=4.9V
R_MD4_R1         VS VB 120k TC=-0.00135415, -2.516e-7
S_MD4_OHS_P         VB MD4_OHS_2 MD4_OHS_1 com _MD4_OHS_P
RS_MD4_OHS_P        MD4_OHS_1 com 1G
.MODEL        _MD4_OHS_P VSWITCH Roff=1e9 Ron=1m Voff=4.9 Von=0.1
S_MD4_OHS_N         MD4_OHS_3 VS MD4_OHS_1 com _MD4_OHS_N
RS_MD4_OHS_N        MD4_OHS_1 com 1G
.MODEL        _MD4_OHS_N VSWITCH Roff=1e9 Ron=1m Voff=0.1 Von=4.9
R_MD4_OHS_R6         HO MD4_OHS_2 11.4 TC=0.00190676, 9.3240e-07
R_MD4_OHS_R7         MD4_OHS_3 HO 7.76 TC=0.00241396, 2.331e-06
C_MD3_C1         com MD3_DlyHS_8  10p
C_MD3_C2         com MD3_DlyLS_8  10p
E_MD3_ABM21         MD3_DlyHS_1 com   VALUE { ( V(VB)
+ -V(VS) )   }
C_MD3_DlyHS_C         VSS MD3_DlyHS_5  10n
S_MD3_DlyHS_delay_P         MD3_DlyHS_20 MD3_DlyHS_5 MD3_DlyHS_2 VSS
+  _MD3_DlyHS_delay_P
RS_MD3_DlyHS_delay_P        MD3_DlyHS_2 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD3_DlyHS_delay_P VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=10 Voff=4.99V Von=0.01V
S_MD3_DlyHS_delay_N         MD3_DlyHS_5 VSS MD3_DlyHS_2 VSS _MD3_DlyHS_delay_N
RS_MD3_DlyHS_delay_N        MD3_DlyHS_2 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD3_DlyHS_delay_N VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=10 Voff=0.01V Von=4.99V
S_MD3_DlyHS_P1         MD3_DlyHS_10 MD3_DlyHS_11 MD3_DlyHS_6 VSS _MD3_DlyHS_P1
RS_MD3_DlyHS_P1        MD3_DlyHS_6 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD3_DlyHS_P1 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=4.9V Von=0.1V
S_MD3_DlyHS_P2         MD3_DlyHS_11 MD3_DlyHS_9 MD3_DlyHS_8 VSS _MD3_DlyHS_P2
RS_MD3_DlyHS_P2        MD3_DlyHS_8 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD3_DlyHS_P2 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=4.9V Von=0.1V
S_MD3_DlyHS_N1         MD3_DlyHS_9 VSS MD3_DlyHS_8 VSS _MD3_DlyHS_N1
RS_MD3_DlyHS_N1        MD3_DlyHS_8 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD3_DlyHS_N1 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=0.1V Von=4.9V
S_MD3_DlyHS_MP1         MD3_DlyHS_12 MD3_DlyHS_13 MD3_DlyHS_9 VSS
+  _MD3_DlyHS_MP1
RS_MD3_DlyHS_MP1        MD3_DlyHS_9 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD3_DlyHS_MP1 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=4.9V Von=0.1V
S_MD3_DlyHS_MP2         MD3_DlyHS_13 MD3_DlyHS_8 MD3_DlyHS_7 VSS _MD3_DlyHS_MP2
RS_MD3_DlyHS_MP2        MD3_DlyHS_7 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD3_DlyHS_MP2 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=4.9 Von=0.1
S_MD3_DlyHS_MN1         MD3_DlyHS_8 VSS MD3_DlyHS_7 VSS _MD3_DlyHS_MN1
RS_MD3_DlyHS_MN1        MD3_DlyHS_7 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD3_DlyHS_MN1 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=0.1 Von=4.9
S_MD3_DlyHS_MN2         MD3_DlyHS_8 VSS MD3_DlyHS_9 VSS _MD3_DlyHS_MN2
RS_MD3_DlyHS_MN2        MD3_DlyHS_9 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD3_DlyHS_MN2 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=0.1 Von=4.9
X_MD3_DlyHS_Comp1         MD3_DlyHS_5 MD3_DlyHS_18 MD3_DlyHS_7 com COMP
X_MD3_DlyHS_Comp2         MD3_DlyHS_3 MD3_DlyHS_5 MD3_DlyHS_6 com COMP
E_MD3_DlyHS_ABM5         MD3_DlyHS_21 com   VALUE { (5-5*EXP(-{toffT2}/10/10n))
+ *(5-5* EXP(-( {toffT1}+({toffT3}-{toffT1})/({T3}-{T1})*(TEMP-{T1}))/10/10n))
+

+ /(5-5* EXP(-( {toffT1}+({toffT3}-{toffT1})/({T3}-{T1})*({T2}-{T1}))/10/10n))
+   }
E_MD3_DlyHS_ABM14         MD3_DlyHS_19 com   VALUE { (1-EXP(-( {toffVdd1}+(
+ {toffVdd3}-{toffVdd1})/({V3}-{V1})*(V(VDD)-{V1}))/10/ 10n))/
+ (1-EXP(-( {toffVdd1}+({toffVdd3}-{toffVdd1})/({V3}-{V1})*({V2}  -{V1}))/10/
+  10n))   }
E_MD3_DlyHS_ABM31         MD3_DlyHS_18 com   VALUE { ( V(MD3_DlyHS_21)
+ *V(MD3_DlyHS_17)
+ *V(MD3_DlyHS_19) )   }
E_MD3_DlyHS_ABM24         MD3_DlyHS_3 com   VALUE { (EXP(-({tonVdd1}+({tonVdd3}-
+ {tonVdd1})/({V3}-{V1})*(V(VDD)-{V1}))/10/10n))/((EXP(-({tonVdd1}+({tonVdd3}-
+ {tonVdd1})/({V3}-{V1})*({V2}-  {V1}))/10/10n)))
+ *(5* EXP(-( {tonT1}+({tonT3}-{tonT1})/({T3}-{T1})*(TEMP-{T1})) /10/
+  10n))/(5* EXP(-( {tonT1}+({tonT3}-{tonT1})/({T3}-{T1})*({T2}-{T1})) /10/
+  10n))*5*EXP(-{tonT2}/10/10n)* (EXP(-({tonV1}+({tonV3}-{tonV1})/({V3}-
+ {V1})*(V(MD3_DlyHS_1)-{V1}))/10/10n))/((EXP(-( {tonV1}+({tonV3}-{tonV1})/({V3}-
+ {V1})*({V2}-{V1}))/10/10n)))   }
V_MD3_DlyHS_V_delay         MD3_DlyHS_20 VSS 5V
C_MD3_DlyHS_C3         VSS MD3_DlyHS_6  10p
V_MD3_DlyHS_VC1         MD3_DlyHS_10 VSS 5V
C_MD3_DlyHS_C6         VSS MD3_DlyHS_9  10p IC=-5V 
C_MD3_DlyHS_C5         VSS MD3_DlyHS_8  10p IC=0V 
V_MD3_DlyHS_VC2         MD3_DlyHS_12 VSS 5V
S_MD3_DlyHS_N2         MD3_DlyHS_9 VSS MD3_DlyHS_6 VSS _MD3_DlyHS_N2
RS_MD3_DlyHS_N2        MD3_DlyHS_6 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD3_DlyHS_N2 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=0.1V Von=4.9V
C_MD3_DlyHS_C4         VSS MD3_DlyHS_7  10p
E_MD3_DlyHS_ABM13         MD3_DlyHS_17 com   VALUE { (1-EXP(-( {toffV1}+({toffV3}-
+ {toffV1})/({V3}-{V1})*((V(MD3_DlyHS_1))-{V1}))/10/ 10n))/

+ (1-EXP(-( {toffV1}+({toffV3}-{toffV1})/({V3}-{V1})*({V2}  -{V1}))/10/ 10n)) 
+   }
C_MD3_DlyLS_C         VSS MD3_DlyLS_5  10n
S_MD3_DlyLS_delay_P         MD3_DlyLS_20 MD3_DlyLS_5 MD3_DlyLS_2 VSS
+  _MD3_DlyLS_delay_P
RS_MD3_DlyLS_delay_P        MD3_DlyLS_2 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD3_DlyLS_delay_P VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=10 Voff=4.99V Von=0.01V
S_MD3_DlyLS_delay_N         MD3_DlyLS_5 VSS MD3_DlyLS_2 VSS _MD3_DlyLS_delay_N
RS_MD3_DlyLS_delay_N        MD3_DlyLS_2 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD3_DlyLS_delay_N VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=10 Voff=0.01V Von=4.99V
S_MD3_DlyLS_P1         MD3_DlyLS_10 MD3_DlyLS_11 MD3_DlyLS_6 VSS _MD3_DlyLS_P1
RS_MD3_DlyLS_P1        MD3_DlyLS_6 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD3_DlyLS_P1 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=4.9V Von=0.1V
S_MD3_DlyLS_P2         MD3_DlyLS_11 MD3_DlyLS_9 MD3_DlyLS_8 VSS _MD3_DlyLS_P2
RS_MD3_DlyLS_P2        MD3_DlyLS_8 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD3_DlyLS_P2 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=4.9V Von=0.1V
S_MD3_DlyLS_N1         MD3_DlyLS_9 VSS MD3_DlyLS_8 VSS _MD3_DlyLS_N1
RS_MD3_DlyLS_N1        MD3_DlyLS_8 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD3_DlyLS_N1 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=0.1V Von=4.9V
S_MD3_DlyLS_MP1         MD3_DlyLS_12 MD3_DlyLS_13 MD3_DlyLS_9 VSS
+  _MD3_DlyLS_MP1
RS_MD3_DlyLS_MP1        MD3_DlyLS_9 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD3_DlyLS_MP1 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=4.9V Von=0.1V
S_MD3_DlyLS_MP2         MD3_DlyLS_13 MD3_DlyLS_8 MD3_DlyLS_7 VSS _MD3_DlyLS_MP2
RS_MD3_DlyLS_MP2        MD3_DlyLS_7 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD3_DlyLS_MP2 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=4.9 Von=0.1
S_MD3_DlyLS_MN1         MD3_DlyLS_8 VSS MD3_DlyLS_7 VSS _MD3_DlyLS_MN1
RS_MD3_DlyLS_MN1        MD3_DlyLS_7 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD3_DlyLS_MN1 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=0.1 Von=4.9
S_MD3_DlyLS_MN2         MD3_DlyLS_8 VSS MD3_DlyLS_9 VSS _MD3_DlyLS_MN2
RS_MD3_DlyLS_MN2        MD3_DlyLS_9 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD3_DlyLS_MN2 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=0.1 Von=4.9
X_MD3_DlyLS_Comp1         MD3_DlyLS_5 MD3_DlyLS_18 MD3_DlyLS_7 com COMP
X_MD3_DlyLS_Comp2         MD3_DlyLS_3 MD3_DlyLS_5 MD3_DlyLS_6 com COMP
E_MD3_DlyLS_ABM5         MD3_DlyLS_21 com   VALUE { (5-5*EXP(-{toffT2}/10/10n))
+ *(5-5* EXP(-( {toffT1}+({toffT3}-{toffT1})/({T3}-{T1})*(TEMP-{T1}))/10/10n))
+

+ /(5-5* EXP(-( {toffT1}+({toffT3}-{toffT1})/({T3}-{T1})*({T2}-{T1}))/10/10n))
+   }
E_MD3_DlyLS_ABM14         MD3_DlyLS_19 com   VALUE { (1-EXP(-( {toffVdd1}+(
+ {toffVdd3}-{toffVdd1})/({V3}-{V1})*(V(VDD)-{V1}))/10/ 10n))/
+ (1-EXP(-( {toffVdd1}+({toffVdd3}-{toffVdd1})/({V3}-{V1})*({V2}  -{V1}))/10/
+  10n))   }
E_MD3_DlyLS_ABM31         MD3_DlyLS_18 com   VALUE { ( V(MD3_DlyLS_21)
+ *V(MD3_DlyLS_17)
+ *V(MD3_DlyLS_19) )   }
E_MD3_DlyLS_ABM24         MD3_DlyLS_3 com   VALUE { (EXP(-({tonVdd1}+({tonVdd3}-
+ {tonVdd1})/({V3}-{V1})*(V(VDD)-{V1}))/10/10n))/((EXP(-({tonVdd1}+({tonVdd3}-
+ {tonVdd1})/({V3}-{V1})*({V2}-  {V1}))/10/10n)))
+ *(5* EXP(-( {tonT1}+({tonT3}-{tonT1})/({T3}-{T1})*(TEMP-{T1})) /10/
+  10n))/(5* EXP(-( {tonT1}+({tonT3}-{tonT1})/({T3}-{T1})*({T2}-{T1})) /10/
+  10n))*5*EXP(-{tonT2}/10/10n)* (EXP(-({tonV1}+({tonV3}-{tonV1})/({V3}-
+ {V1})*(V(VC)-{V1}))/10/10n))/((EXP(-( {tonV1}+({tonV3}-{tonV1})/({V3}-{V1})*(
+ {V2}-{V1}))/10/10n)))   }
V_MD3_DlyLS_V_delay         MD3_DlyLS_20 VSS 5V
C_MD3_DlyLS_C3         VSS MD3_DlyLS_6  10p
V_MD3_DlyLS_VC1         MD3_DlyLS_10 VSS 5V
C_MD3_DlyLS_C6         VSS MD3_DlyLS_9  10p IC=-5V 
C_MD3_DlyLS_C5         VSS MD3_DlyLS_8  10p IC=0V 
V_MD3_DlyLS_VC2         MD3_DlyLS_12 VSS 5V
S_MD3_DlyLS_N2         MD3_DlyLS_9 VSS MD3_DlyLS_6 VSS _MD3_DlyLS_N2
RS_MD3_DlyLS_N2        MD3_DlyLS_6 VSS 1G
.MODEL        _MD3_DlyLS_N2 VSWITCH Roff=1e6 Ron=1 Voff=0.1V Von=4.9V
C_MD3_DlyLS_C4         VSS MD3_DlyLS_7  10p
E_MD3_DlyLS_ABM13         MD3_DlyLS_17 com   VALUE { (1-EXP(-( {toffV1}+({toffV3}-
+ {toffV1})/({V3}-{V1})*((V(VC))-{V1}))/10/ 10n))/

+ (1-EXP(-( {toffV1}+({toffV3}-{toffV1})/({V3}-{V1})*({V2}  -{V1}))/10/ 10n)) 
+   }

.ENDS    IR2110

.SUBCKT COMP 1 2 3 4
E1 5 4 VALUE={IF((V(1)>V(2)), V(4)+5V, V(4))}
R1 5 3 1
C1 3 4 10P
.ENDS

then after some reading I've think that apparently the lines with the definitions are the problem and I beleive that are specially those that have the "+" sign juste after the definition of the name and and definitions of the pins but a can't be shure.

I'm actually reusing the model of the IR2112 which has the pin asignment and package defined but I don't know how to manage some of the parameters of the plus lines.

I know with the model of the IR2112 I could work but: Can anyone help me with this problem?, is a way of learning more of proteus better said spice.

Thanks in advance for the help.

I've forgot to tell that the property SPACEPINS of the model in proteus is written this way: VDD,HIN,SD,LIN,VSS,HO,VB,VS,VC,COM,LO; the same order of the spice model.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I've found in labcenter's forum that this model isn't compatible in all parameters with the spice simulator of proteus, then I need to modify it and that specific task is a work that I don't need to do right now so I'm simulating it with the IR2112 which has similar charecteristics.